# Vim treats unicode characters as a separate text object from english alphabets

Tags: string, text, vim, neovim

I use both of vim and neovim, but just found that both editors treat unicode characters (such as Korean characters) as a different text object from english alphabet separately.

For instance, if there is a text, `my_str = 'ABC가나다'`, vim only removes `ABC` if I type `dw` at `A`.

Of course I would be able to use `di'` instead, but it's getting annoying with using surrounding.vim plugin.

Typing `ysw[` only surrounds `ABC` because Vim recognizes `가나다` as a separate text object even tough there is no space between the two.

Will there be any solution for this?

Thank you so much.
June

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/vim-does-not-take-umlauts-as-word-characters might give some ideas for getting it to work.